# Is there an adjective that describes the shape of jigsaw puzzle pieces?

Tags: word-request

Is there an adjective that describes the shape of jigsaw puzzle pieces? I am pretty sure there's an adjective for it, but I am not sure I can think of any.

Comment: irregularly shaped

Comment: No standard term, but see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47667/what-do-you-call-the-interconnecting-bits-of-a-puzzle-piece-in-english

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are trying to describe them. There are many adjectives you could use to describe the way jigsaw puzzle pieces are shaped. Here are a few suggestions: [jagged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jagged), irregular, [asymmetrical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asymmetrical), unique. There are many more adjectives you could use, it just depends on what aspect of the jigsaw puzzle pieces you are trying to describe. Maybe you are trying to describe the fact that each piece has a unique shape? Or perhaps you are trying to describe that they tend to be [asymmetrical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asymmetrical)? Thus, the adjective that describes the shape of jigsaw puzzle pieces is specific to what you are trying to describe about them.